# iOS keep keyboard open when tab a specific element

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uikeyboard

I have a UITextView and a Button.
I need that the keyboard stays opened when the user taps the button.

I tried to use the ShouldEndEditing function to return False, but then the user can never close the keyboard again.

Any ideas?

I'm using Xamrin Forms.

Comment: Do you have a minimum complete verifiable example you can post?  Otherwise without any other info, I suspect you'll likely have to change the ShouldEndEditing to return false only when you want the keyboard to remain open, and then true when it's ok to close the keyboard.  It seems right now you just return false, always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C you would set a Done Editing event in the view controller, which would immediately re-open the keyboard.. with no visual change.

```
-(IBAction) textFieldDoneEditing : (id) sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [sender becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Xamarin / C# equivalent.. off the top of my head.

```
txtMyTextBox.Ended += (sender, e) =>
{
    txtMyTextBox.ResignFirstResponder();
    txtMyTextBox.BecomeFirstResponder();
};
```

Comment: You could also run txtMyTextBox.BecomeFirstResponder(); as part of your Button handler

Comment: Try dropping the first command, so just

`txtMyTextBox.Ended += (sender, e) =>
{
    txtMyTextBox.BecomeFirstResponder();
};`

Comment: Yes, that kept the keyboard always open. Even the the user taps the button to close the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, interesting question and you have already known about the property "ShouldEndEditing" in UITextFieldDelegate, so why don't you try to implement a custom delegate for your UITextField?

I wrote a sample for you and I use a UISwitch to simulate the condition for hiding the keyboard, in your ViewController, use the code below:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            MYTextFieldDelegate myDel = new MYTextFieldDelegate ();

            UITextField textTF = new UITextField ();
            textTF.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (50, 50, 200, 40);
            textTF.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            textTF.Delegate = myDel;
            this.Add (textTF);

            UIButton btnTest = new UIButton (UIButtonType.System);
            btnTest.SetTitle ("Test", UIControlState.Normal);
            btnTest.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (50, 100, 200, 40);
            btnTest.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                this.View.EndEditing (true);
            };
            this.Add (btnTest);

            UISwitch keyboardSwitch = new UISwitch ();
            keyboardSwitch.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (50, 150, 200, 40);
            keyboardSwitch.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
                bool flag = (sender as UISwitch).On;
                myDel.FlagForDisplayKeyboard = flag;
            };
            this.Add (keyboardSwitch);
        }
```

And this is MYTextFieldDelegate.cs:

```
class MYTextFieldDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate
    {
        public bool FlagForDisplayKeyboard { get; set; }

        public override bool ShouldEndEditing (UITextField textField)
        {
            return FlagForDisplayKeyboard;
        }

        public MYTextFieldDelegate ()
        {
            FlagForDisplayKeyboard = false;
        }
    }
```

Hope it can help you.